# Using a x-speed transmission with a DC motor

Tags: motor, dc, remote-control

I would like to ask whether there is any point in using a transmission with different gears (like the gearbox in a car) with a DC motor?

For instance in an RC car.  Are there any benefits to using a smaller gear ratio to decrease the rpm of the motor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no advantage to a transmission with a variable ratio like the gearbox in cars. With current technology, electric motors with electronic speed controllers can provide a sufficient range of speed adjustment for most vehicles.

There may be a need for a fixed-ratio gear to match the electric motor drive system to the vehicle.

If there is something preventing the best design from being used for the electric motor drive system, a variable-ratio transmission could compensate for that. There may also be some unusual vehicle requirement that could benefit from a variable-ratio transmission.

Mechanical transmissions have the advantage of providing pretty-much constant power at any selected speed. The disadvantages are some wasted power due to gear friction, increased drive-train mass and volume, and added maintenance requirements.